# Using pointers to obtain data and use them in another function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have to have a function (Lets call it Data) that uses pointers in order to store 3 different float values as local variables in main and then use those values in another function that does some calculations.

Comment: And what is your doubt  ? Show the code you tried  ?

Comment: basically im asking how do i just use a function to store variables while using pointers. all i have is void GetData(float*, float*, float*) im not sure how to write a function thats sole purpose is to store values.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void StoreData(float *PlaceToStoreData, float DataToStore)
{
    *PlaceToStoreData = DataToStore;
}

float UseDataDirectly(float DataToUse)
{
    return DataToUse * DataToUse;
}

float UseDataIndirectly(float *PlaceWhereDataIs)
{
    return *PlaceWhereDataIs * *PlaceWhereDataIs;
}

int main(void)
{
    float MyData;

    StoreData(&MyData, 2.71828f);

    printf("%f\n", UseDataDirectly(MyData));

    printf("%f\n", UseDataIndirectly(&MyData));
}
```